# How can i control page throught javascript inside an iframe of that page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have an iframe with Js code to run, and i wan't to control the iframe DOM options and css style.
How can i do it? If you wan't to use jQuery, thats ok, but i preffer pure javascript...

Things that i want to modify:
- frameborder
- css styles (float, display, position, overflow)
- no scrolling bar

**EDIT**: The code run's **inside** the iframe

Thanks

Comment: Where will the code run, in the parent page or inside the iframe?

Comment: Does the page inside the frame run on the same domain as the outlying document? (Although gathering from your previous questions, I think the answer is no.)

Comment: @Pekka No, that's why i'm choosing the iframe method :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume from your previous questions that the document inside the iframe is *not* on the same domain as the outlying page.

In that case, your options are extremely limited, again because of the [Same Origin Policy](http://code.google.com/p/browsersec/wiki/Part2#Same-origin_policy). You will not have Javascript access to the elements or CSS of the outlying page. That includes the `<iframe>` element on that page.

Any design decisions you will therefore have to put inline into the `iframe` tag:

```
<iframe frameborder="0" style="float: left; width: 500px; height: 200px ....">
```

I think that applies to everything you mention except the scroll bar behaviour: That you can control inside the iframe document using the `body` element's `overflow` property.

The only alternative idea that comes to mind is have the sites that embed your iframe also include a style sheet that comes from your domain in the `head` section of the document. That CSS you would, of course, fully control.

If you limit the design rules in that CSS to your iframe (e.g. by using the `#id` selector), that would work as well. The downside is that if the style sheet does *not* get included, your iframe will break. This is why most providers of widgets use inline CSS.

Comment: so.. i will have to create a JS to create the iframe, receive the information on json, and apply it to the iframe?

Comment: @CuSS yup, that would work I guess. Hadn't thought of that, good idea!

Comment: But @CuSS in that case, you could dynamically generate the script already with the proper styles in it as inline. That will save you one request

Comment: @Pekka my script loads the id of the ad, for example: `$('.MicrodualAdGet').attr('id');` will read from user DOM `<div class="MicrodualAdGet" id="3"></div>`, then i could create an iframe inside the div (or replace it), make the `GET` request with all information (size, on click url, image url, etc), and then replace iframe content with html code generated by javascript. I think this will bypass the SOP cookie problems...

Comment: I will try it, thanks @Pekka, you're a great person, i must have your email ahaha

Comment: @CuSS you can have my E-Mail, but only to buy me gifts from my Amazon Wish list! :P

Comment: AHAHAHAHAHHA, @Pekka if i were rich, that would be ok AHAHHA